# Not able to see a contact in Marketing Cloud after synchronizing the Contact Object

Tags: marketing-cloud

My contact object is synchronized with Marketing Cloud. I added a contact in the CRM but is not showing under All Contacts neither under the Contact sync data extension. The synchronized data extension for the contact object is refreshing correctly. Any ideas why this could be happening? Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm you don't see this field when you go to Contact Builder > Data Sources > Synchronized > [Select your connector] > Contact and then click on "Edit Fields" on the right top ? It's not in the list (even unchecked)?

Comment: Is not an issue with a sync DE field. I created a contact in the crm but is not showing on the Contact Sync data extension. Could it be a matter of permissions? i don t have the Marketing Cloud connected app permission. I read thatAll end-users who plan to use Marketing Cloud Connect to send emails, need this permission set assigned to their user record in the Salesforce CRM org. I don t have the Marketing Cloud for AppExchange Admin” and “Marketing Cloud for AppExchange User” either. Maybe the contact on the CRM is not going to MC because of that.

Comment: OK sorry I thought it was an issue with a new field.
Do you already have contacts synchronized between the CRM and MC ?
If you don't have any contact synchronized yet, it might be an issue with your permissions, yes. You should check all necessary boxes.
If you already have, do you have any criteria in your connector which can limitate the kind of contacts to enter in MC ? To check this last point : Contact Builder > Data Sources > Synchronized > [Select your connector] > Contact and then on the left part check if under "RECORDS COLLECTION" you have "All records" written here.